# Promise Rejection Error when starting a new transaction section with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to create a new session, but get the following error code in the terminal: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: dbClient.startSession is not a function` and a few more lines below: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

The way I use it is by setting up a db (i.e. mongo) client in a dedicated utils file like this:

```
require('dotenv').config()

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

const ATLAS_URL = `my-atlas-url`
const MONGO_OPTIONS = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}
let database

const connectToDB = callback => {
  MongoClient.connect(ATLAS_URL, MONGO_OPTIONS, (error, db) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    database = db.db(process.env.ATLAS_DB_NAME)
    callback()
  })
}

const get = () => {
  return database
}

const startNewSession = () => {
  MongoClient.startSession()
}

const closeDBConnnection = () => {
  MongoClient.close()
}


module.exports = {
  connectToDB,
  get,
  startNewSession,
  closeDBConnnection,
}
```

Inside my app / index.js file I call this function:

```
dbClient.connectToDB(() => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Connected to MongoDB. App running on PORT ${PORT}`)
  })
})
```

And then, when I want to create a new session in a route like this: `const session = dbClient.startNewSession()` according to the official [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) I get the error mentioned above.

I get that it's a promise error, but I can't figure out why and where this error is happening.

Comment: `MongoClient.startSession()` - `startSession` is an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed an important part in my setup, so of course I need to init a session way earlier:

```
let database
let session

const connectToDB = callback => {
  MongoClient.connect(ATLAS_URL, MONGO_OPTIONS, (error, db) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
    database = db.db(process.env.ATLAS_DB_NAME)
    session = db
    callback()
  })
}

const startNewSession = () => {
  return session.startSession()
}
```

This way I can simply have `const session = dbClient.startNewSession()` in whatever route I need it.